TYPO3 12: Slug part for extension is not added
I have added a slug field to my extenson (tt_board) and its part is not added to the final urls.
Example-Url:
https://myextension.mydomain.com/themen-1/forum-1/?tt_board_tree%5Buid%5D=33&cHash=88a53836a77cd019b1858eab1ae064da


Even in the backend the prefix "https://myextension.mydomain.com" should not be there, because the extension has only a slug part which must be added to the slug of the page.
On another extension (tt_products) I have only the slug part shown in the TYPO3 backend (without the url prefix).

  TtBoardTree:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/boardt/{board}'
    namespace: tt_board_tree
    requirements:
      board: '[\w].*'
    aspects:
      board:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tt_board
        routeFieldName: slug

I have searched the docs for several times and compared both extensions. Does anyone give me the hint how I must fix this?
All the code is here
config.yaml
